# С++ Взаимодействие между class и наследование

Tags: c++, классы

На скрине ниже (код я не понял как красиво сюда вставить, кашу выдаёт) мне нужно сделать так, чтобы 2 разных класса могли взаимодействовать друг с другом, например один это враг, а второй это мы как пользователь или игрок (я всё на игры перевожу, так проще) и нужно, чтобы враг наносил урон игроку, а игрок врагу. Сделать формулы не сложно, сложно сделать так, чтобы были взаимодействия между обоими классами.

И мне хотелось бы знать:

1. я вообще в том направлении иду или надо иначе делать, если так, то будьте добры подкинуть тем для изучения и хоть какой пример без этих надоевших Х и Y, брррр.
2. Если всё же направление верное, то как мне объявить переменные в главном (мамином) классе, ибо ругается только на него и причина тому - необъявленная переменная health от класса Enemy в классе Player.
   2.1. Я знаю что можно сделать переменную health  в главном классе, но там чехарда с указателями начинается, если же то, что я делаю в данный момент в принципе не жизнеспособно, то подскажите на моём примере как сделать правильно.
   P.s. На скрине и код и ошибка ниже в логе.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   class Library {
   public:
       class Player &p;
       class Enemy  &e;
   };
   class Player : public Library{
   public:
       int health;
       Player *p;
       void test()
       {
           p->health = 100;
           e.health = 123;
       }
   };
   class Enemy : public Library{
   public:
       int health;
       Enemy *e;
       void testEnemy()
       {
           e->health = 666;
           p.health = 123;
       }
   };
   ```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы всё же вставьте код. Там кнопочка есть, или просто отступ в 4 пробела

Comment: Можно добавить предварительную декларацию классов над местом их использования, чтобы компилятор понял, что класс будет чуть позже) `class Enemy; class Player;`

Comment: .Разобрался как код сюда добавлять и добавил соответственно. Так же попробовал сделать как советов комментатор с ником *vp_arth*, но не работает, ошибка всё та же.

Igor, отличный комментарий, очень исчерпывающий.

Comment: @Ka3 - вам следует усвоить, что ruSO не является сервисом психологической поддержки для начинающих айтишников. Человек, столкнувшийся с похожей проблемой и ищущий ответ, будет вынужден продираться через пространное описание ваших личных переживаний, что является неуместным в данном случае. Больше сути и фактов, меньше эмоций.

Comment: *gbg* ,благодарен за комментарий, приму к сведению.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, незачем множить "здоровья", во-вторых, родительский класс по хорошему не должен ничего знать о наследниках, и тем паче содержать их (неинициализированные ссылки) в себе, в третьих, нельзя использовать необъявленный класс, в четвертых...

Словом, я бы делал так:

```
class Character
{
protected:
    int health;
public:
    Character(int h):health(h){}
    int getHealth() const { return health; }
    void setHealth(int h) { health = h; }
};

class Enemy;

class Player : public Character
{
public:
    Player(int h):Character(h){}
    void test(Enemy& e);
};

class Enemy : public Character
{
public:
    Enemy(int h):Character(h){}
    void testEnemy(Player&p);
};

void Player::test(Enemy& e)
{
    health += 100;
    e.setHealth(e.getHealth()-123);
}

void Enemy::testEnemy(Player&p)
{
    health += 666;
    p.setHealth(p.getHealth()-123);
}
```

Comment: Только вместо `e.setHealth(e.getHealth()-123);` я бы сделал `e.gotDamage(123)`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ну, можно и так :) Тогда имеет смысл сделать такой метод чисто виртуальным в классе `Character`.

Comment: Искренне благодарю за ответ, как прибуду домой обязательно опробую и начну разбираться почему это работает именно так. Бегло прочитав, я вспомнил книгу Липмана, где подобное говорили, возможно не совсем вник, ещё раз душевно благодарю Вас.

Comment: Благодарности (и недовольства) здесь имеют форму треугольников и птичек слева от ответа :)